# How to display this product has cart rule in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, cart-rules

For prestashop 1.6 We have set cart rules for specific product, by adding 3products, another 1 product would be added as gift,

This is all working well on cart page,

but how to display this on that specific product page

```
$context::$this->$cart->$getCartRules();
```

not showing on product page

We have to display cart rule on specific product which is having respected cart rules,

```
ex. "buy this product and you will get xyz product for free"
```

Answer (score 1):

i think u will have to build your own query selecting the cart_rules with your gift_product id that still actives.

Add an static method in CartRule (or where u need) and call in the product.tpl directly and show it

ex: `{CartRule::getGifts($product.id)}`  then, handle the result

Answer (score 0):

Build custom query for the same :

```
$result = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
            SELECT *,rg.quantity as minimum_quantity FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule_value` cv 
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule` pr ON cv.id_product_rule = pr.id_product_rule 
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule_group` rg ON pr.id_product_rule_group = rg.id_product_rule_group
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule` cr ON cr.id_cart_rule = rg.id_cart_rule
                WHERE cv.id_item = '.$this->id_product.' AND cr.gift_product > 0 AND cr.date_to >= "'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'"'
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in **Product.php**

```
 public function getRule($category = "0"){
   $rules = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT *,rg.quantity as minimum_quantity FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule_value` cv 
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule` pr ON cv.id_product_rule = pr.id_product_rule 
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule_group` rg ON pr.id_product_rule_group = rg.id_product_rule_group
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule` cr ON cr.id_cart_rule = rg.id_cart_rule
            WHERE code = "" and ((cv.id_item = '.$this->id.' and type = "products") or (cv.id_item = '.$category.' and type = "categories")) AND cr.date_to >= "'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'"'
    );
    return $rules;
}
```